# How to query data from an object from Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch data of all the users having cardNumber: 3243 using the following model using mongoose.

```
cred: {
     nameValue: 'anonymous',
     emailValue: 'anonymous@gmail.com',
     passwordValue: 'anonymous121',
 },
 location: {
     addressValue: 'anonymous address',
     cityValue: 'anonymous',
     stateValue: 'anonymous',
     postalValue: 122133344,
 },
 card: {
     cardName: 'anonymous',
     cardNumber: 3243,
     securityCode: 123,
     expirationMonth: 7,
     expirationYear: 2031,
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the model is called `User`, you simply need to use the Mongoose [findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) query method.

For example, using dot-notation for the query:

```
User.findOne({'card.cardNumber' : 3243}).exec(callback)
```

This will return one result with the cardNumber value of 3243